# Calling a class function inside of other function PHP

Tags: php, class

I created a class that has a function.
And I want to use this class function inside of a new function.
But my code is no t working, I don't know where im doing it wrong.

```
 <?php

class Pagination {

    function page_core() {
        global $conn;

        $per_page = 16;
        if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }
        $limit = 'LIMIT ' . (($page - 1) * $per_page) . ', ' . $per_page;
        $start_from = ($page > 1) ? ( $page * $per_page ) - $per_page : 0;
    }    
}
```

And I'm calling my function page_core inside of other function like this...

```
<?php

    function gallery_full() {
    $pagination_core = new Pagination();
    $pagination_core->page_core();
    .....html code.....
```

OBS:I'm new in php.

Comment: What is the error or condition you are experiencing?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: start_from in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\clientes\gallery\gallery_includes\gallery_function.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined variable: per_page in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\clientes\gallery\gallery_includes\gallery_function.php on line 39

Comment: stop using global variables, stop using string concatenation and learn to indent code

Answer (score 0):

You've neglected to declare $start_from as a global variable prior to calling the page_core() function.  Using global variables in this manner isn't a good practice, however.  A better method would be to declare and return $start_from from within page_core().  Something like `return $start_from;`